# A script works by its own, but doesn't work from another script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

The scripts sc2 works when I run it by itself, but gives some strange error, when I try to run it from another script.

```
#!/bin/bash

function print {
while read name; do
echo $1 $name
done
}

function find_suspect {
while read domain; do
echo $domain
sc2 $domain|print 1
sc3 money|print 2
sc3 new ideas|print 2
sc4 3|print 3
done
}

#main
find_suspect $* | sort -k1 | sort -sk2 | uniq -f1
done
```

The problem is in sc2:

```
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
/homet2/s3218517/mtm/ex1/scripts/sc2: line 4: ((: >0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is ">0")
```

This is sc2:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls | while read file; do
    if ((`sc1 $file $LAST_SENT_EMAILS_TO_CONSIDER | cut -d"@" -f2 | grep "$1" -c -w`>0)); then
        echo $file  
    fi
done | sort
```

This is received and sent: 
Received:

```
0   kevin@animation.com 2015-11-30  09:14   Notes from the meeting
1   shannon@animation.com   2015-11-29  08:21   Some new ideas for movies
```

Sent:

```
scott@gmail.com 2015-11-30  23:14   Thanks for the awesome present!
dan@animation.com   2015-11-29  22:15   Some cool reviews
erin@gmail.com  2015-11-29  09:35   Vacation this summer
```

sc2 prints all the names of the workers, which mailed to or from the given domain (as parameter).

In sc5 I gain few domains, and want to print for them all, all the names of the workers (with the number 1 aside) as sc2 does with a while loop. What is wrong in the realization ?

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Always quote your variable expansions. Add `set -x` to the top of a script to see what it is actually executing at each line. Where is `find_suspect` getting input from?

Comment: Where is `$LAST_SENT_EMAILS_TO_CONSIDER` in sc2 coming from?

Comment: The second is from exporting it's value. find suspect gets it's inputs from the user by $* (all the domains I give in the command line calling sc5 <domain1> <domain2> <domain3> ... 
Didn't understand about variable expansion (you mean workers=`ls`, if you do, then ls gimes me all the workers names as they exist in the main directory. and each worker has sent and received file). I didn't got you at the set -x eather, can you write it expansively (maybe as an answer) ?

Comment: please edit your question to show small sample inputs, required outputs, current outputs, error messages and code.Only include verbal description as in your comment as a last resort. The code, data, required output, the current wrong output, and error messsages should be able to tell 90% of the story. Then we can copy/paste, run it ourselves, and not have to guess where the problems are. Good luck.